# Error connecting to getstream php

Tags: php, curl, getstream-io

I am following the example at https://getstream.io/get_started/?language=php to understand how getstream io works. I ran into an error that got me confused.

```
 require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
 $client = new GetStream\Stream\Client('YOUR_API_KEY',     'API_KEY_SECRET');
$chris = $client->feed('user', 'chris');
 // I replaced Your api key and api key secret with the one         in my dashboard
// Add an activity; message is a custom field - tip: add unlimited         custom fields!
$data = array(
"actor" => "chris",
"verb" => "add",
"object" => "picture:10",
"foreign_id" => "picture:10",
"message" => "Beautiful bird. Absolutely beautiful. Phenomenal bird."
);

$chris->addActivity($data);


// jack's 'timeline' feed follows chris' 'user' feed:
$jack = $client->feed('timeline', 'jack');
$jack->followFeed('user', 'chris');


// Read the 'timeline' feed for jack, chris' post will now show up: 
$activities = $jack->getActivities(10);
var_dump($activities);
```

In my composer.json file I did this

```
       "require": {
        "get-stream/stream": "2.2.8"
        }
```

I tried the above code on my localhost machine on windows but got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\ExceptionConnectException'     with message 'cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\CorpersMate\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 186
 GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in C:\xampp\htdocs\CorpersMate\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 186
```

any ideas guys?

Comment: @mimarcel I am a novice. I followed the guide and I got that error.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have the single-quote after SECRET? It seems that's breaking the code. Or is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later found a tweak to the problem. The problem is with the guzzle library which is trying to verify my certificate. Because I needed a way to test it on local server before moving to production server, I had to modify the client constructor in the guzzle library and that solved the problem for me.

```
 // file name is Client.php 

  public function __construct(array $config = ['verify' => false]) {
    if (!isset($config['handler'])) {
        $config['handler'] = HandlerStack::create();
    }

    // Convert the base_uri to a UriInterface
    if (isset($config['base_uri'])) {
        $config['base_uri'] = Psr7\uri_for($config['base_uri']);
    }

    $this->configureDefaults($config);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should provide guide - we have to register first to get it, it can't happen.

Change second line to

```
$client = new GetStream\Stream\Client(KEY, SECRET);
```

Comment: Please check if you have openssl with phpinfo()

Comment: openssl support is enabled and library version is OpenSSL 1.0.11

Comment: I just tried it on production server and it is working fine. I wonder why it is not working on Xampp

Answer (score 0):

I'll dig into why this doesn't work on Xampp for you. Can you send us your cURL options, library version, etc.?

In the meantime, based on the workflow you've built:

1. build a feed for Chris
2. build an activity and put it on Chris' feed
3. build a feed for Jack
4. Jack follows Chris' feed
5. read Jack's feed and expect to see Chris' activity

... Jack will need to specify a number of activities to copy when following Chris' feed, otherwise Jack will only see updates from that point on; Jack will never see "picture:10" from Chris. There's a third optional parameter you can send through followFeed() that specifies how many items to copy to Jack's feed when you start following:

```
$jack->followFeed('user', 'chris', 100);
```

Or you can move step 4 between step 1 and 2. If Jack follows Chris before Chris adds a photo, it should show up on Jack's feed.

Comment: @michail_w if you could contact me at support@getstream.io I've got some followup questions about your platform, version of xampp, etc., so I can reproduce this for you to help find a solution.